# LuaInterface C#: dostring vs dofile. Is it worth loading a script that will be called numerous times into memory?

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

Can anyone tell me if I can reasonably expect any performance gain by loading a lua script that will be called repetitively into memory for execution through LuaInterface's **`dostring()`** functionality rather than **`dofile()`**?

Am I correct in assuming this will perform better by reducing file-system access each iteration?

Is there some way to cache the script within the **Lua VM**?

Comment: Are you using LuaJIT?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used lua, but I think both of them are deprecated in favour of first calling something like `LoadFile` and then executing it in a second step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute some lua code for many times, the better way is using LoadFile OR LoadString.
Load lua code as a LuaFunction, like:

```
LuaFunction lf = xxx.LoadString("some lua code");   // xxx is an instance of LuaInterface
lf.Call();   // you can also deliver some arguments
```

This is much faster than DoFile AND DoString.
Because it needs just one time compiling.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in assuming this will perform better by reducing file-system access each iteration?

In general, you should benchmark rather than assume, but this is pretty cut and dried: "disk IO, compile, execute" vs "execute". Of course the latter is going to be faster.

> Is there some way to cache the script within the Lua VM?

Whether you `dofile` or `dostring` any globals your script produces will be available for you to read/call. If you want to avoid your scripts modifying the VM's global namespace, you can expose an API routine (in the host) that your script can call to register a callback.